# DLL, error: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I compiled the Dynamic-link library in the QtCeator & MinGW compiler:

.pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-04-01T04:51:46
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       -= gui

TARGET = kuins_method
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += KUAINRULE_EXPORTS

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    ../kuins_method_file/abstractnormalform.cpp \
    ../kuins_method_file/abstractobject.cpp \
    ../kuins_method_file/constituent.cpp \
    ../kuins_method_file/expression.cpp \
    ../kuins_method_file/initkuainrule.cpp \
    ../kuins_method_file/kuainrule.cpp \
    ../kuins_method_file/normalform.cpp \
    ../kuins_method_file/perfectnormalform.cpp \
    ../kuins_method_file/shortnormalform.cpp

HEADERS += \
    ../kuins_method_file/abstractnormalform.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/abstractobject.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/constituent.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/defines.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/expression.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/global.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/initkuainrule.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/kuainrule.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/normalform.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/perfectnormalform.h \
    ../kuins_method_file/shortnormalform.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

Global file that was connected to the entire project:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H

#ifdef _MSC_VER

    #ifdef KUAINRULE_EXPORTS  
    #define KUAINRULE_API __declspec(dllexport)   
    #else  
    #define KUAINRULE_API __declspec(dllimport)   
    #endif

#elif __MINGW32__

    #include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

    #ifdef KUAINRULE_EXPORTS
    #  define KUAINRULE_API Q_DECL_EXPORT
    #else
    #  define KUAINRULE_API Q_DECL_IMPORT
    #endif

#else

    #error MSVC or Qt + MinGW compiler required.

#endif

#endif // GLOBAL_H
```

I added a macro next to each imported function

Here is an example:

```
namespace nsKuainRule {

    class NormalForm : public AbstractNormalForm, public AbstractObject
    {
        std::vector <Expression> _expressionNFs;
    public:
        /**** CONSTRUCTOR & DESTRUCTOR ****/
        KUAINRULE_API NormalForm();
        KUAINRULE_API ~NormalForm();

        /**** OVERRIDE FUNCTIONS ****/
        /*!
         * \brief Get all expressions from the NF class
         * \return Vector of \a Expression objects
         */
        KUAINRULE_API std::vector<Expression> &getAllExpr() override;
        KUAINRULE_API std::string print() const override;
    };

}
```

Release and debug were compile without errors

After that, I tried to connect the library to a new project.
New Qt console application project was created.
All *.h files were added to project as existing files.
I clicked "Add Library..." and chose options

[image: Add library dialog box]

.pro file

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    abstractnormalform.h \
    abstractobject.h \
    constituent.h \
    defines.h \
    expression.h \
    global.h \
    initkuainrule.h \
    kuainrule.h \
    normalform.h \
    perfectnormalform.h \
    shortnormalform.h

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lkuins_metho
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/./ -lkuins_method

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/.
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/.
```

All files  *.а, *.dll, *.h , I copied to the root directory

compilation errors: undefined reference to ...

Please help me solve this problem.
What wrong did I do?
If you want to view the whole project, please follow the link: https://github.com/OleksandrMyronchuk/minimize-logical-functions

Errors:

```
A:\qtProject\build-del3-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\main.o:-1: In function `main':
A:\qtProject\del3\main.cpp:21: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11nsKuainRule13InitKuainRuleD1Ev'
A:\qtProject\del3\main.cpp:21: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11nsKuainRule13InitKuainRuleD1Ev'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What comes after the `...` part of that error?  Can you show the entire compiler output?

Comment: A:\qtProject\build-del3-Desktop_Qt_5_10_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\main.o:-1: In function `main':
A:\qtProject\del3\main.cpp:21: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11nsKuainRule13InitKuainRuleD1Ev'
A:\qtProject\del3\main.cpp:21: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11nsKuainRule13InitKuainRuleD1Ev'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: In your comments you talk about a `vtable`, but in your full error log there is no mention of any `vtable`!

Comment: Let me suggest one thing outside the scope. Since you are building with QtCreator, it commonly caches a lot of build output and doesn't reliably re-link correctly after making a Makefile or .pro file changes.  Have you tried exiting Qt Creator and then deleting everything from the `build-` folder where all your project output files are stored?  I often have to delete the build folder, then restart QtCreator, and then "build clean" from the menu there to get it to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug of Qt Creator. I clicked to "Build" -> "Clean All", after that errors disappear.

Thank you, Selbie and everyone else !
Problem was solved